# Exporting html table excel using java script. not exporting when it find '#' chracter

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I need a JavaScript to export HTML tables to Excel. 
I have tried this script, it is exporting but when it found special character i.e '#' it stopping there it self
not exporting further lines.

can anyone help me out,thanks in advance

```
<script src="/tpComment.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            \$(function() {
            \$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('dvData');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    window.open(data_type + ', ' + table_html);
    e.preventDefault();
     //getting values of current time for generating the file name
});
});
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="CreateExcelSheet()" value="Create Excel Sheet">
<div id="dvData" >
<table >
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th> address </th>
    <th> no </th>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>#17 </td>
    <td>99999</td>
    </tr></table></div>
```

Comment: Why the \$ format and you have indow.open - which should be window.open

Comment: You need to url-encode `table_html` (beyond just replacing spaces with %20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I am using URL encoding.below script is working fine for special characters.
My solution may helpful for others.

```
 <script src="/tpComment.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#dvData').html()));
e.preventDefault();
});
});
```